# Black transparent overlay has some disturbance in UI - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a custom modal popup box. To show or hide the modal box, I've used JQuery code. Below is my CSS style code and JQuery code

**CSS**

```
    .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        background: #000;
        opacity: .8;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display:none;
        z-index: 999
    }

 .modal {
     position: absolute;
    margin: 30px auto;  
    background: #fff;
    display:none;
    height: 200px; 
    width:600px;
    top: 60px;     
  }
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
function showModal(){
   $('.overlay').show(); 
   $('.modal').fadeIn(100);
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal_title">My Title</div>
   <div class="modal_inner">
       My Modal Content
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, it's showing below output.
[image]
[image]

I want to remove this disturbance from UI. But need to know why it's appearing?
Is my code wrong? or Is there any other possibilities of this issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you recreate the issue so we can see it happening for ourselves? An image doesn't really help much unless you can actually reproduce the error.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am not sure what exactly cause is there so I am unable to recreate this for you. But I can show you a video. I also got one thing, while showing / hiding the modal, the system is increasing opacity 0 - 1 with an increasing point by point. Well, I think this is because of fadeIn effect but I think because of this it's not working. Please see video here  https://youtu.be/qsXTUVpMoes

Comment: Then it sounds like artefacts in your monitor not a CSS issue at all.

Comment: have exactly same issue with primeng dialog. No idea what might be causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not something caused by your code, but by the browser. Confirm by trying to use other browsers too.

There unfortunately isn't much you can do. You can wait for them to fix it, or you can try a different approach which happens to not screw up with the rendering, but those are the only options as I see it.

Comment: Thanks. But is it a problem with only my Chrome browser or every?

Comment: No idea, go try it out. Could easily be graphics driver related, could be related to hardware acceleration, or could be a generic bug.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to achieve something like this:

```js
   $('.overlay').show(400, function() {
      $(this).append($('.modal'));
      $('.modal').fadeIn(1000)
   });
```

```css
 .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        background: #000;
        opacity: .8;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 999;
    }

 .modal {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 30px auto;  
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    height: 200px; 
    width:600px;
    top: 60px;     
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal_title">My Title</div>
   <div class="modal_inner">
       My Modal Content
   </div>
</div>
```

You should use callbaks in order to make it work consecutively like overlay -> modal. That disturbance is related to fading in your modal - it is hapenning at the same time as the overlay appeares. They overlap and get animated so we see some weird visual effect related to page rendering while animating.